# TYPO3 Version 6.0 import from CSV or DB query

Tags: sql, csv, import, typo3

I have a CSV file which contains these columns - Timestamp, Author, Title and Content. 
Now I would like to import this CSV into TYPO3, so that I can display a list of posts containing these attributes.

If the above is not possible, is there a way to write in manual SQL queries, so that I can manually insert content into TYPO3 ?

I have tried many extensions for importing CSV- wil_import, rs_impory, external import .. but none of them work !!

In the following image, I have installed wil_import, but It does not show up anything. 
Do I need to make any changes anywhere else, like configuration or something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use phpmyadmin's CSV import functionality. It works reliably.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem once and my day was saved thanks to Francois Suter's (Core team member) extensions: [svconnector](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/svconnector) and [svconnector_csv](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/svconnector_csv). So, I can really recommend them